# Java Queue Program Results to Empty When Dequeueing

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.*;





class Customer {
       public String lastName;
       public String firstName;
       public Customer() {
       }
       public Customer(String last, String first) {
          this.lastName = last;
          this.firstName = first;
       }
       public String toString() {
          return firstName + " " + lastName;
       }
    }
    class HourlyCustomer extends Customer {
       public double hourlyRate;
       public HourlyCustomer(String last, String first) {
          super(last, first);
       }
    }

class GenQueue<E> {
   private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
   public void enqueue(E item) {
      list.addLast(item);
   }
   public E dequeue() {
      return list.poll();
   }
   public boolean hasItems() {
      return !list.isEmpty();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
       return list.isEmpty();
   }
   public E removeFirst(){
       return list.removeFirst();
   }
   public E getFirst(){
       return list.getFirst();
   }
   public int size() {
      return list.size();
   }

   public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {
      while (q.hasItems()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
   }
}





public class something {

    public static void main(String[] args){



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        String input2;
        int choice = 1000;




        GenQueue<Customer> empList;
        empList = new GenQueue<Customer>();
        GenQueue<HourlyCustomer> hList;
        hList = new GenQueue<HourlyCustomer>(); 

        while(true){

        do{

            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Queue Operations Menu");
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("1,Enquene");
            System.out.println("2,Dequeue");
            System.out.println("0, Quit\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
            try{

                choice = sc.nextInt();



                switch(choice){
                case 1:

                    do{


                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter last name:  ");
                    input1 = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter first name:  ");
                    input2 = sc.next();
                    hList.enqueue(new HourlyCustomer(input1, input2));
                    empList.addItems(hList);

                    System.out.println("\n"+(input2 + " " +  input1) + " is successful queued");

                    System.out.println("\nDo you still want to enqueue?<1> or do you want to view all in queue?<0> or \nBack to main menu for dequeueing?<menu>: ");
                    choice = sc.nextInt();

                    }while (choice != 0);



                     System.out.println("\nThe customers' names are: \n");

                     while (empList.hasItems()) {
                     Customer emp = empList.dequeue();
                     System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n" );
                     }

                     break;






                case 2:


                    if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("\nDequeued customer: "  +empList.getFirst());
                    empList.removeFirst();
                    }

                    if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("\nNext customer in queue: "  +empList.getFirst()+"\n");
                }

                    break;

                case 0:

                    System.exit(0);



                default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                }

            }

            catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter 1-5, 0 to quit");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

        }while(choice != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a program that accepts queue and then can also dequeue. in case 1 i made the queue successfully, but at case 2, i encountered a certain trouble that I cant figure out that I have to stack overflow it, Im stuck here and I might just be missing out the trivial things on this code. So I need your help. Why does in case 2 my dequeue gets passed an empty list? How do i fix this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

when you populate your hlist you dequeue all elements from empList and hence your empList will be empty at last.

while (q.hasItems()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());

You can rewrite your addItems method, to just iterate over the elements in the given queue and add them to its own LinkedList.

Comment: Do you mean `iterator.add()` ?  So I add this on rewrite this on my addItems method, or maybe create another one perhaps @Ehsan

Comment: You can iterate on the LinkedList items like this:

for(E item : q.list)
{
     list.addLast(item);
}

Comment: another way is to use addAll:  list.addAll(q.list);

Comment: I rewrote my addItems to the code i upvoted, I think its at the part in case 1 where empList goes empty, is in the while loop. 
`while (empList.hasItems()) {
                     Customer emp = empList.dequeue();
                     System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n" );
                     }
`      So how do I turn use the new addItems? 

I think its around here where it goes empty `Customer emp = empList.dequeue();`  I tried turning this to `Customer emp = empList.addItems();` but the method is undefined. @Ehsan

Comment: why do you dequeue elements from empList in order to print them in stdout? if you want not to just print the information of customers in the queue and not remove them from the queue one simple workaround is to implement an iterator function in your GenQueue class which returns the list.iterator. Then use that iterator in the while loop in case 1 in order to go through all elements in your queue and print them.